# First derivative in matlab

Tags: matlab, diff, derivative

I want to calculate the first derivative of a function with matlab. However, I do not know the function's formula, I only have access to its inputs and outputs.
For instance:

```
f([1 2 3 4 5]) = [1 4 9 16 25]; %Square function for the example
```

I am not satisfied of the output of:

```
diff([1 2 3 4 5]) %Which is [3 5 7 9]
```

I have seen on this forum that I am not the only one trying to calculate the first derivative of a function with matlab. But since, I don't know the mathematical formula of my function, I can't use the symbolic Math Toolbox.

So my questions are:

- How can I calculate the derivative of a function in matlab by only knowing its inputs and outputs?
- Can I find a way to retrieve the mathematical formula of my function, so that I can use the symbolic Math Toolbox?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with `diff`? What specific problem does it have?

Comment: @Luis it doesn't give you `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`, which is the derivative of `x^2`:P

Comment: @JaneDoe on a serious note: there's an area of applied mathematics called "numerical differentiation". If you don't know the underlying function, you have to approximate. Google with this keyword and see what you find.

Comment: You could do a `polyfit` and then just differentiate that?

Comment: Or just sample the function over a very fine grid and then you can could do a lot with it (numeric derivatives/integrals, curve fits, transforms etc.).

Comment: For what's it's worth the values `[3 5 7 9]` lie on the line formed by `y = 2*x` when `x = 1 2 3 4 5`.  You just need the right x values to match the y's you have.

Comment: you're looking for finite difference approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference. There's also a clever variation of this using complex step differentiation which usually has higher precision: http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can evaluate the function easily, here is a vary simple way to estimate the derivative. (Assuming the function behaves nicely)

```
x = 1:5
h = 0.0001;

dir_est= (f(x)-f(x+h))/h
```

Note that this is very similar to the definition of the derivitive.

Comment: You may also choose (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem as described I would use a combination of `polyfit` and `polyval` with a brute force approach.  Something like this.

```
in = [1 2 3 4 5];
out = fun(in); % in this case, simply y = x.^2 
epsilon = 0.000001;
test = inf;
best = 0;
% some large term count
test = inf;
best = 0;
for n = 0:7
    p = polyfit(in, out, n);
    val = sqrt(sumsqr(polyval(p, in) - out));
    if ((val < test) & (abs(val - test) > epsilon))
        best = n;
        test = val;
    end
end
p = polyfit(in, out, best);
syms x, f;
expo = best:-1:0;
f = p * (x.^expo).';
```

Then you can use symbolic math on the variable `f`.  For the example you provided this returns a polynomial dominated by `x^2`.

However, it seems like the better approach would be to use either the definition of the derivative or more robust numerical methods then a simple difference as others have suggested.